# JComboBox inside a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I'm having trouble putting a javax.swing.JComboBox into a org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable cell. I browsed the before questions about this problem, but non helped.

I tried:

```
colModel.getColumnExt(HDTableAdapter.STATUS).setCellEditor(editorCB);  
colModel.getColumnExt(HDTableAdapter.STATUS).setCellRenderer(rendererCB);

class comboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

    public comboBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
        super(items);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }

        setSelectedItem(value);
        return this;
    }
}

class comboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public comboBoxEditor(String[] items) {
        super(new JComboBox(items));
    }
}
```

But in this case, I get a not-editable ComboBox inside the cell.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick them

Comment: why are you surprised? JComboBox is _not_ editable by default ...

Comment: one comment chasing the other <g> Just noticed the JXTable bit: _dont_ implement a renderer (ever in SwingX!), instead subclass ComponentProvider for unsupported component types (there are examples in xxVisualCheck in the test section, xx == Renderer or == JXTable (probably, dont recall exactly)

Comment: By not editable, I mean When I click on it, the list doesn't show up so I cannot change the value.

Comment: you understand the term "convention", right? Then learn the ones specific to java ;-)

Comment: should be - assuming the cell is editable. Something wrong with your code elsewhere, time for an sscce (respecting the java naming conventions :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your ComboxEditor looks wrong.. use this instead:

```
class ComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    public ComboBoxEditor(String[] items) {
    super(new JComboBox(items));
    JCombobxToolTipRenderer renderer = new JCombobxToolTipRenderer();
    ((JComboBox)editorComponent).setRenderer(renderer);
}

public ComboBoxEditor(ComboBoxModel aModel) {
    super(new JComboBox(aModel));
    JCombobxToolTipRenderer renderer = new JCombobxToolTipRenderer();
    ((JComboBox)editorComponent).setRenderer(renderer);
}
}

class JCombobxToolTipRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
            value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    if (-1 < index && null != value) {
        list.setToolTipText((String) value);
    }
    return comp;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what JCombobxToolTipRenderer / JComboBoxToolTipRenderer  should be.. ?

Comment: random code snippet (don't mimic @mKorbel in that respect :-) The OP's editor is just fine and should work as-is - after all, it's just a convenience subclass with exactly the same functionality as its super.

Comment: Oops.. sorry.. didnt spend any time looking at the class I had written a long time back. I use these classes and everything works just fine for me.. Have you subclassed the TableColumnModel? Could you post that code?

Comment: Just realised that you are using SwingX's TableColumnModelExt class, instead, if you try this it might work:TableColumnModel columnModel=getColumnModel();
  
  ComboBoxRenderer renderer=new ComboBoxRenderer(data);
  ComboBoxEditor editor=new ComboBoxEditor(data);
  columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(renderer);
  columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellEditor(editor);

Comment: SwingX has nothing to do with the OPs perceived problem (bet it's exactly the same with core) ... which is still unreproducible for all others because s/he doesn't show an sscce. BTW, you can edit your answer - code in comments is difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class FinCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{

    Component component;

    private JTextField text;
    private JComboBox combo;
    private int rowIndex;

       public FinCellEditor(){
                text = new JTextField();
              combo =new JComboBox();
       }

    @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
               Object select = null;
               if(rowIndex==9||rowIndex==10){
               select = combo.getSelectedItem(); 
               return select;
               }else{    
               if(select!=null){
                  text.selectAll();
               } 
               select = text.getText();
               return select;
               }
        }
    @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
              if (row == 7) {      
                  date.setEnabled(true);
                  rowIndex=row;
                  return date;
              }else if (row == 9) {
                 combo.removeAllItems();
                 combo.addItem("Male");
                 combo.addItem("Female");
                 rowIndex=row;
                 return combo;
            }else if (row == 10) {
                 combo.removeAllItems();
                 combo.addItem("Married");
                 combo.addItem("UnMarried");
                 rowIndex=row;
                 return combo;

           } else {
                text.setEnabled(true);
                rowIndex=row;
                return text;
           }
       }
```